# Does Aerospike support Location based queries like in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, aerospike

MongoDB supports the following type of location based query. Does Aerospike support this?

```
var db = req.db,
        find = {
        'loc' : {
            '$near' : {
                '$geometry' : {
                    'type' : 'Point',
                    'coordinates' : [lon, lat]
                },
                '$maxDistance' : radius
            }
        }
    },
```

If Aerospike supports this, then what is the correct syntax to be used in NodeJS client?

Comment: It does now in its Early Adopter Release!

Answer (score 1):

Aerospike just announced the Early Adopter Release for its Geospatial features. See more info on the [Announcements](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-geospatial-index-query-early-adopter-release/2193) page.

Answer (score 1):

Aerospike Server Community Edition 3.7.0 is now out, and it includes Geospatial Indexes.

Aerospike can now store GeoJSON objects and execute various queries, allowing an application to track rapidly changing Geospatial objects or simply ask the question of “what’s near me”. Internally, we use Google’s S2 library and Geo Hashing to encode and index these points and regions. The following types of queries are supported:

- Points within a Region
- Points within a Radius
- Regions a Point is in

This can be combined with a User-Defined Function (UDF) to filter the results – i.e., to further refine the results to only include Bars, Restaurants or Places of Worship near you – even ones that are currently open or have availability. Additionally, finding the Region a point is in allows, for example, an advertiser to figure out campaign regions that the mobile user is in – and therefore place a geospatially targeted advertisement. Internally, the same storage mechanisms are used, which enables highly concurrent reads and writes to the Geospatial data or other data held on the record. Geospatial data is a lot of fun to play around with, so we have included a set of examples based on Open Street Map and Yelp Dataset Challenge data.

Geospatial is an Experimental feature in the 3.7.0 release. It’s meant for developers to try out and provide feedback. We think the APIs are good, but in an experimental feature, based on the feedback from the community, Aerospike may choose to modify these APIs by the time this feature is GA. It’s not intended for Production usage right now (though we know some developers will go directly to Production ...)

Answer (score 0):

No. Geospatial location datatype and indexes on them is not yet supported in Aerospike. When it is available, you should not be expecting a document structure based query mechanism. Aerospike is not a document store.